# The Axiom of Choice implies that every topological vector space has a balanced base and every locally convex space has a balanced convex local base.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, set-theory, axiom-of-choice, topological-vector-spaces

**What is shown below is a reference from the text *Functional Analysis* by Walter Rudin.**

If $X$ s a vector space over the field $\Bbb F$ then  the following notation well be used
$$
x+A=\{x+a:a\in A\}\\
x-A:=\{x-a:a\in A\}\\
A+B:=\{a+b:a\in A\wedge b\in B\}\\
\lambda A:=\{\lambda a:a\in A\}
$$
for any $A,B\subseteq X$, for any $x\in\ X$ and for any $\lambda\in\Bbb F$.

> **Definition**
>
> If $\tau$ is a topology on a vector space $X$ such that
>
> 1. every point of $X$ is a closed set
> 2. the vector space operation are continuous with respect to $\tau$
>
> we say that $X$ is a topological vector space equipped with the vector topology $\tau$.

So we note that the condition $1$ imply that any topological vector space will be $T_1$ but many authors omitted the above condition from the definition of a topological vector space.

> **Proposition**
>
> Let be $X$ a topological vector space over the field $\Bbb F$ and for some $v\in X$ and $\lambda\in\Bbb F$ we define the $v$-traslation and $\lambda$-multiplication functions through the condition
> $$
> T_v(x):=x+v\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,M_\lambda(x):=\lambda x
> $$
> for any $x\in X$. So the above two defined functions are homeomorphisms.
>
> *Proof*. Omitted.

One consequence of the above proposition is that every vector topology $\tau$ is translation-invariant, that is a set $E\subseteq X$ is open if and only if each of its translates $v+E$ is open and thus $\tau$ is completely determined by any local base so that the open sets of $X$ are then precisely those that are unions of translates of members of any local base. **In a vector space context, the term local base will always mean a local base at $0$. A local base of a topological vector space $X$ is thus a collection $\mathscr B(0)$ of tneighborhoods of $0$ such that every neighborhood of $0$ contains a member of $\mathscr B(0)$$**.

> **Definition**
>
> Let be $X$ a topological vector space over the field $\Bbb F$ of the real or complex numbers. So a subset $C$ of $X$ is said convex if
> $$
> tC+(1-t)C\subseteq C
> $$
> for any $t\in[0,1]$. Then a subset $B$ of $X$ is said balanced if
> $$
> \alpha B\subseteq B
> $$
> for each $\alpha\in\Bbb F$ such that $|\alpha|\le 1$.
>
> **Theorem**
>
> In a topological vector space $X$ over the field $\Bbb F$ of the real or complex numbers every neighborhood of $0$ contains a balanced neighborhood of $0$ and every convex neighborhood of $0$ contains a balanced convex neighborhood of $0$.
>
> *Proof*. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2839661/theorem-1-14-b-rudin-functional-analysis-few-clarifications).

So the last theorem can be restarted in terms of local bases so that let us say that a local base $\mathscr B$ is balanced if its members are balanced sets and let us call $\mathscr B$ convex if its members are convex sets.

> **Corollary**
>
> Every topological vector space has a balanced local base and every locally convex space has a balanced convex local base.

So I ask to discuss if to prove the above corollary is necessary to use the Axiom of Choice. Indeed to prove the above corollary I use the following argumentation. So the by the previous theorem it seems to me that we can claim that exist a function $f$ from the neighborhood system of $0$ in the neighborhood system of $0$ such that $V_U:=f(U)$ is a balanced neighborhood of $0$ contained in $U$ and precisely the above theorem states that we can make this function picking for any $U$ (surely we can thought that $0$ has no many finite neighborhoods!) another nneighborhood of $0$ that is balanced and here contained and to do this I do not know if we have to use the Axiom of Choice. Then clearly the last corollary is true for a local base of the null vector so I ask to explain if it is true for a local base of another different point. So could anyone help me, please?

Comment: In section 1.7, Rudin writes "In the vector space context, the term _local base_ will always mean a local base at $0$. A local base of a topological vector space $X$ is thus a collection $\mathscr{B}$ of neighborhoods of $0$ such that every neighborhood of $0$ contains a member of $\mathscr{B}$." So the corollary only speaks about neighbourhoods of $0$. And it must, because every nonempty balanced set contains $0$, thus in a Hausdorff TVS (Rudin considers only such, $T_1$ is part of Rudin's definition of a TVS), no point other than $0$ can have a balanced neighbourhood basis.

Comment: Okay. Anyway could I ask why every nonempty balanced set contains the zero vector? Perhaps this is true because if in the definition of the balanced set we put $\alpha:=0$ then $\alpha B=\{0\}$, right?

Comment: Yes. And by the $T_1$-requirement, every point $x \neq 0$ has a neighbourhood not containing $0$, which therefore doesn't contain any balanced neighbourhood of $x$.

Comment: Okay, thanks too much for your assistance!

Comment: So you want to know, essentially, if there is a canonical way to make a neighbourhood (of $0$) balanced (in a way that preserves convexity). Given *a* neighbourhood of $0$, how do you produce a balanced one?

Comment: No, I know that if U a neighborhood (eventually convex) of $0$ then there exist a balanced (and eventually convex) neighborhood V of $0$ contained there  so that the collection of all such neighborhoods is a local base. So I ask you formally make this collection: I try to do this implementig the above result with a function $f$ as described in the question but unfortunately I do not know if to do this I have to use the Axiom of Choice. So what can you say about?

Comment: And I say, read my comment *again*. You are asking if there is a canonical way to assign to a (convex) neighbourhood a (convex) balanced sub-neighbourhood. If there is no canonical way, then we can start looking at examples where there are no such way and try to use these to construct actual counterexamples. So *essentially* the first question is, is there a canonical way. And I also ask *how* can you prove there is one? You say that you "know", but presumably this knowledge comes from somewhere.

Comment: You don’t need the axiom of choice to prove the existence of a balanced (convex balanced, resp.) local base: just let $\mathscr{B}$ be the set of all balanced (convex balanced, resp.) nbhds of $0$. The theorem immediately implies that $\mathscr{B}$ is a local base. You can’t get a balanced local base at any other point, but if you have a convex balanced base at $0$, you can translate it to any other point $x$ to get a convex local base $\mathscr{B}_x$ at $x$. Moreover, it will be ‘balanced’ at $x$ in the sense that $x+\alpha(B-x)\subseteq B$ for each $B\in\mathscr{B}_x$ and $\alpha\in[0,1]$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Umm...perhaps I understand what you mean. The theorem that I posted in the question says that for any neighborhood $U$ of $0$ there exist a balanced neighborhood of $0$ that is contained there but it effectively did not give a canonical way to make a balanced local base so properly as you say my question is exactly to find a canonical way to make a balanced local base, right?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Oh yeah, I understood! Now it is all clear. Thanks too much for your assistance!!!

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: You’re welcome!

Comment: Antonio, the theorem, for all I know, says "every infinite set contains a countably infinite subset therefore bla bla bla". You omit the proofs. I don't know these proofs. Does the proof that every neighbourhood contains a balanced one rely on AC? You're not telling me. You just keep telling me that "it's known". To whom? To you, yes. To me, no. But you're asking me about a consequence of that theorem, which is why I am asking you about it, over and over again.

Comment: I put the proof of the theorem: anyway it seems to me that it does not user the Axiom of Choice.